# CSS Text effects for Internet Explorer Question?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Is there a way I can add a border or text shadow to text in Internet Explorer?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by a "border shadow for text"?

Comment: can i give my text a text-shadow or outline border?

Comment: @Yi Jiang: I think he means a 'stroke' colour? But I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: It's actually really easy. Take a snapshot of what your website looks like in Firefox, then use JavaScript to detect IE browsers and load that image while hiding everything else.

Answer (score 1):

borders are easy, put the text in a span, and set the border of the span:

```
<span style="border: 1px solid red;">This text will have a border</span> the rest wont.
```